# Create a SharePoint Modern Team Site with PNP PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, pnp

I tried to create a new Modern SharePoint Site with the PNP Framework. I ran in the following error. I want to store the Url in a variable. Everytime I store it in a variabel I get an error message:

```
New-PnPSite : The property or field 'Url' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be 
explicitly requested.
```

I don't where the error is coming from.

Here is my code so far:

```
$AdminURL = "https://{tenant}-admin.sharepoint.com"
$SiteTitle= "Test1238"
$SiteUrl= "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/Test1238"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminURL -Interactive

New-PnPSite -Type TeamSiteWithoutMicrosoft365Group -Title $SiteTitle -Owner $SiteOwner -Lcid 1033 -Url $SiteUrl
```

Thanks for the help

Best regards

Matthias

Comment: I just tried the same code provided by you and it is working fine for me. Try [Updating PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/installation.html#updating-pnp-powershell). Also, are you passing the hardcoded `$SiteUrl` as shown in your code or getting it dynamically from somewhere else? What is the value you passed for `-Owner` (In `$SiteOwner` variable)?

Comment: Also, try this: `$newSiteUrl = New-PnPSite -Type TeamSiteWithoutMicrosoft365Group -Title $SiteTitle -Owner $SiteOwner -Lcid 1033 -Url $SiteUrl`. Let me know if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't have the same problem as you. Why not try [the SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online)?

```
#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -url "https://domain-admin.sharepoint.com" -Credential (Get-credential)

#Create a modern team site
New-SPOSite -Url "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename" -Owner "user@domain.Onmicrosoft.com" -StorageQuota 2048 -Title "sitename" -Template "STS#3"
```